# Using SwiftUI view in WatchKit and Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchkit, watchos

I'm building a watch app with `WatchKit` and storyboard.
I have a `SwiftUI` view that I want to use as a subview beside the other Storyboard items in a `WKInterfaceController`.

The `SwiftUI` view:

```
struct SliderView: View {
    @State private var speed = 50.0

    var body: some View {
        CompactSlider(value: $speed, in: 0...100, step: 5) {
            Text("Speed")
            Spacer()
            Text("\(Int(speed))")
        }
    }
}
```

This `SwiftUI` view lays just fine on a separate controller using `WKHostingController`, but this is not what i want.

```
class HostingController: WKHostingController<SliderView> {
    override var body: SliderView {
        return SliderView()
    }
}
```

How can I use this `SwiftUI` view on Storyboard or `WKInterfaceController`?

Comment: WKHostingController is-a WKInterfaceController, so you can use it as any other controller inherited from WKInterfaceController.

Comment: If I try to drop any element like a group or button on `WKHostingController` it just doesn't work, it doesn't drop.

Comment: No, you use only SwiftUI inside WKHostingController, but controller, as instance, use as usual WKInterfaceController.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to set a subview in `WKInterfaceController`. How would i use the instance of it as a subview?